# Rendering particles vs ALT+D copying the object

Tags: rendering, particles, optimization

I have a simple question.

Is it better for render time and optimization to add for example Trees as particle system or to ALT+D duplicate it as many times as i need. What will be easier for memory?

Comment: I understand that. But which one would be the most render efficient. Which one is best optimization

Comment: For memory more optimal would be using linked duplicates (or better collection instances via shift+a > collection instance). But that won't be too convenient to place manually on the surface of the object like particles. This is implemented as multiple instances of one object only oriented differently in some other render engines but not in Cycles afaik. Maybe that will change with Cycles development

Comment: It should be pretty much the same as both methods will instance the same mesh data. So there will always only be a single instance of the mesh in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is another way to "duplicate" objects, called "linking objects" (not entirely sure what it's called). But basically, you duplicate it as Alt + D, but it remains somehow part of the original mesh.

Alternatively you could use multiple array modifiers.